# Doubts upgrading Ubuntu Server from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade from 14LTS to 16LTS.

I just tried it now on my 14LTS and received:

```
 # do-release-upgrade
 Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 No new release found
```

I’m not quite sure where to possibly start. High-level:

(1)SERVER1 ->
(2)HOST1 (uses approx. for a local cache) -> VPN->
(3)REMOTE_UPSTREAM_REPO -> 
(4)Ubuntu servers

I control/manage (1) and (2), but don’t have access to (3).

Where might the issue be? Probably at (3)? What might I need from them?

I know I’m running 14LTS with the Xenial kernel, but perhaps that doesn’t mean they have all the Xenial repos at (3)?

Comment: I'd check in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`. If it has `Prompt=never`, change it to `Prompt=lts`. If the repositories you use do not have Xenial, I doubt there is anything we can do. The obvious thing is to try and find out if that is the case.

Comment: This may make no difference, but ensure the 14.04 LTS box is fully upgraded (`sudo apt dist-upgrade`) before attempting do-release-upgrade.    fyi: 14.04 LTS (with HWE enabled) uses the 16.04 LTS kernel from 'trusty' archives, not 'xenial'.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither worked.  I'm going to break off from (3) and set my own local mirror using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror.

Comment: I did a network trace of the do-release-upgrade command, and came across an HTTP GET for http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts (https://makandracards.com/makandra/12439-setup-an-ubuntu-mirror-that-enables-local-release-upgrades).  I'm probably still going to break off from (3), but this seems to clarify a few things with how (3) might have needed meta-release-lts copied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it all working with Debmirror, some custom modifications to the meta-release-lts file (see link in comments above), and a separate script to copy the dist-upgrader-all directories/files.

Sorry, I don't have all the steps detailed to post here...