# Patching after do-release-upgrade

Tags: do-release-upgrade

[Upgrading versions issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114211/upgrading-versions-issue/1127916)

Continuing a bit from above, I managed to get some systems to upgrade from Ubuntu 14 to 16.

Now, after that's done, the systems aren't able to do any subsequent upgrades.

I know this is not the latest version of the kernel on my "patching server":

```
root@FOO:/etc/apt# apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-lts-xenial is already the newest version (4.4.0.142.148).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libio-string-perl
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@FOO:/etc/apt#
```

I've done a `apt-get update` to make sure I'm pulling down any new lists of packages.  An `apt-get upgrade` after that turns up nothing to update, which is definitely not right if everything is working.

I'm going to keep troubleshooting and adding information here as I come up with anything that might be valuable.

Comment: fyi: the linked page talks about upgrading 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.  Canonical/Ubuntu do have releases that are *yy* in format, eg. Ubuntu Core 16 for IoT, the more generic releases have *yy.mm* format releases as they have more than a single release per year.

Comment: I'll keep reviewing.  I have my own local repo server and it worked fine to do the upgrade from 14 to 16.  None of the suggestions have worked so far, so I'll keep digging.

Comment: I just noticed that I have a "Hash Sum mismatch" in my apt-get update output for "xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages".  Something must have missed up during the v14->v16 OS upgrade.